# Groupby and conditional replace

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to group values by a particular column (id's) and replace all values withe the max datetime associated with a given id.

This is the code I have written (doesn't work)

```
file.groupby('data__id')['data__answered_at'].apply(lambda x: x['data__answered_at'] == x['data__answered_at'].max())
```

This is a sample of my dataframe

```
data__id     data__answered_at
1              2019-01-10
1                  Na 
2              2019-01-12
2                  Na
3                  Na
4                  Na
4                  Na
5                  Na
5              2019-01-15
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors='coerce'` for replace non datetimes to `NaT`, then get maximum value per groups with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html), so possible replace missing values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['data__answered_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data__answered_at'], errors='coerce')

s = df.groupby('data__id')['data__answered_at'].transform('max')
df['data__answered_at'] = df['data__answered_at'].fillna(s)
print (df)
   data__id data__answered_at
0         1        2019-01-10
1         1        2019-01-10
2         2        2019-01-12
3         2        2019-01-12
4         3               NaT
5         4               NaT
6         4               NaT
7         5        2019-01-15
8         5        2019-01-15
```

Your solution should be rewritten with lambda function and `fillna`:

```
f = lambda x: x.fillna(x.max())
df['data__answered_at'] = df.groupby('data__id')['data__answered_at'].apply(f)
```